# problem with jquery $.ajax and french characters when inserted in database

Tags: jquery

I get french characters who look like this Ã©  but are é for example.
I am using jquery ajax and making a form validation with php then inserting in the database,
i have try many things but nothing seems to get rid of the problem and i know it's because of jquery ajax because if i make a simple insert in database using only PHP eveything works fine.

```
$(function(){
 $('#submit_maj_password_email').click(function(){
var _data= $(this.form).serialize()
//var encodedString = escape($("#email1").val());
 alert(_data)
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'valid.php?var=maj_password_email',
        beforeSend: function(){},
        data:_data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
         $('div#error').html(html)

         }
     })
})

})
```

php file:

```
<?php
if($_POST and $_GET["var"]=="maj_password_email"){ 
extract($_POST);  //we automatically extract $ variables
...validation....
...insertion in db.....
if( $password!=="default"  and password($password)==true ){
    $query=mysql_query("UPDATE sdf_inemails SET emails_email='$email' , emails_password=md5('$password')  WHERE  emails_id = '".$_COOKIE['_ID']."'")or die(mysql_error());
//mail
  }
}
?>
```

nothing seems to work help.
Regards

Comment: This is an encoding issue. What encoding are your HTML pages and database connection using? Note that Ajax requests serve UTF-8 data by default, that's probably where your problem is.

Comment: Good (but extensive) reading to understand encodings: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: the database has the default sql charset "latin swedish ci" i also tried with the jquery ajax contentType option but i still get same errors, the web pages have charset=iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Pekka said, AJAX requests serve UTF-8 data by default.

When you extract the data of the $_POST variable, you must use utf8_decode, like so:

```
$email = utf8_decode($_POST["txtEmail"]);
```

And then save it to your database.

You also can not forget to set the correctly headers in both of your PHP and HTML pages.

Example HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Example PHP:

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup the encoding type for your database tables and each fields which contains french data.
Most probably **ISO-8859-1** would be the correct encoding type for French.

EDIT

put an echo in server script to verify the data before saving. then you can find out where the problem starts.

```
<?php

$sql = "INSERT INTO {$TABLE} xxxxxx";
echo $sql;
```

Comment: It stands to reason that nowadays, UTF-8 is really the correct encoding for every language.

Comment: it's doesn look to be a problem with the DB as i said when not sending thru ajax french chars shows correctly, and the charset in the DB is the default wich is "latin swedish ci"

Comment: @tada. You can put an echo in the server script before saving the records. So that you can verify data is in correct format.
for example. echo $SQL;